# HTML/Javascript spoiler script not working in IE (Show/Hide)

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="z1" onclick="document.getElementById('q1').style.display='';     document.getElementById('z1').style.display='none';" style="border:solid 1px; background-    color: #DDDDDD; width:936px; height:auto; margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;">
<h2>&nbsp;Pg. 419-423, problems 8-14 even, 20-30 odd, AYP 1-10</h2></div>
<div id="q1" onclick="document.getElementById('q1').style.display='none';     document.getElementById('z1').style.display='';" style="display:none; border:solid 1px;         background-color: #DDDDDD; width:938px; height:auto;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;">
<h2>&nbsp;Pg. 419-423, problems 8-14 even, 20-30 odd, AYP 1-10</h2>
</br>
<img src="http://www.rediker.com/reports/samples/Attendance-Period/Homework-Assignment-        form.jpg"></img></div>
```

The above script is what I planned on using to create a spoiler. Basically, when the user clicks on the z1 element, it hides itself and shows the q1 element, and vice-versa. It works on all browsers besides IE. Linking Jquery would be a small liability.

Comment: Inline javascript???  looks bad.

Comment: jQuery is not needed. It is plain javascript.

Comment: Is this live on a real website that we can visit?

Comment: I didn't tag jquery, it was edited by Huagism.

Comment: @Bill Greg

No, but it is within two tables on a basic document, and all the javascript referencing the two elements are inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.  You're missing to add `display: block`

Change this

```
document.getElementById('z1').style.display='';
```

to

```
document.getElementById('z1').style.display='block';
```

You should think about cleaning your code.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="z1" onclick="aa()"></div>
<div id="q1" onclick="bb()"> 
    <img src="http://www.rediker.com/reports/samples/Attendance-Period/Homework-Assignment-form.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function aa() {
    document.getElementById('q1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('z1').style.display = 'none';
}

function bb() {
    document.getElementById('q1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('z1').style.display = 'block';
}
```

[**Working JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KZX5G/)

Comment: Still having issues with IE.

Comment: I'm having some exterior issues but I think your code is fine, thanks a bunch, I'll get back to you soon

Comment: @KrokosPro I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Apparently the issue had to do with my specific browser blocking "ActiveX controls" or some shit. I never actually use IE for anything but testing so I guess I'm fine. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Usually happens with IE :)